# Variable not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files, my index and my JS file.

In my index I will have a form of input fields and my index file will be linked to my JS file.

In my JS file I will have a list of variables which will get their values from my index file `input` fields. I plan on then multiplying some of my values together in a function.

What is the correct way of doing this without returning `NaN` or `undefined`?

I've been trying to do by setting var values onkeyup or onclick as 'document.getelementbyid'  only it never returns anything...

Some sample code would be,
HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="ServiceLevel" value="0.84" name="ServiceLevel"onclick="getValue()"/>
<input type="radio" id="ServiceLevel" value="0.67" name="ServiceLevel" onclick="getValue()"/>
<input type="radio" id="ServiceLevel" value="0.56" name="ServiceLevel" onclick="getValue()"/>
<input type="radio" id="ServiceLevel" value="0.28" name="ServiceLevel" onclick="getValue()"/>
<input type="radio" id="ServiceLevel" value="0.14" name="ServiceLevel" onclick="getValue()"/>
```

and JS

```
var ServiceLevel = document.getElementById(ServiceLevel).value;
var EstimatedCoreHours = 10;

// Cost Estimate
var CostEstimate = ServiceLevel * EstimatedCoreHours;

function CalculateEstimate() {  

alert('test = ' +CostEstimate);

// Estimate Cost
parseInt(document.getElementById("PriceEstimate").innerHTML=CostEstimate.toFixed(2));

// Estimate Core Hours
parseInt(document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").innerHTML=EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(2));

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do if one or several values are missing? Treat them as `0` (which would make the result `0`)? Or refuse computation? In general you can convert strings easily into numbers using the unary `+` operator.

Comment: some sample codes of yous would add a flavour

Comment: @* - bleh long day never mind.  :)

Comment: I'm curious as to what you think `parseInt(a = b)` does?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this check:

```
var ServiceLevel = document.getElementById(ServiceLevel).value;
var EstimatedCoreHours = 10;

 // Cost Estimate
CostEstimate = ServiceLevel * EstimatedCoreHours;

function CalculateEstimate() {  

alert('test = ' +CostEstimate);

// Estimate Cost
parseInt(document.getElementById("PriceEstimate").value=CostEstimate.toFixed(2));

// Estimate Core Hours
parseInt(document.getElementById("EstimatedCoreHours").value=EstimatedCoreHours.toFixed(2));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values in the javascript. Here is how you should do

Create a file index.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input id="a1" name="a1">
<input id="a2" name="a2">
<input id="a3" name="a3">
<input type=button onClick='Calculate()'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function Calculate()
{
   var v1 = document.getElementById ("a1").value;
   var v2 = document.getElementById ("a2").value;
   var v3 = document.getElementById ("a3").value;
  var total =  GetNumeric (v1) + GetNumeric(v2) + GetNumeric(v3);
}


function GetNumeric(val) {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(val))) {

          return 0;
     }

     return parseFloat(val);

}
```

Comment: As it is arithmatic operation, assured to return "Float" instead of string if success. However can store the value in a variable and return without parsing two times.

Comment: Yes, I know what `parseFloat` does. Indeed, doing it twice seems daft.

Answer (score 0):

1. first thing is

`var ServiceLevel = document.getElementById(ServiceLevel).value;`

`// ServiceLevel = null`

this should be in function else while opening this web page getElementById will give null.

2
. your input radio button has same name & ID if this is the case which value should be taken OR they are Individual OR Group